# Multiple nested array from MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm using foreach loops to access records in a nested array.

I need to nest 3 arrays (so the first array contains an array, which also contains an array). I'm having success with 2 arrays but I can't get 3 to work.

I had my code working with 2 arrays (which worked just fine) but I can't get 3 arrays to be nested.

This is the result that I want:

```
[
  {
    "site_id": "1",
    "user_plants": [
      {
        "user_plant_id": "1",
        "site_id": "1",
        "plant_id": "1",
        "plant_images": [
          {
            "plant_image_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "plant_image_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "plant_image_id": "3"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current code:

```
 $query = "SELECT A.site_id FROM sites A WHERE A.user_id='".$user_id."' GROUP BY A.site_id";
    $result = $this->conn->query($query);

    $json_response = array();
    $sites = array();
    if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {

        while ($item = $result->fetch_object())
            $sites[] = $item;

        foreach($sites as $item) {
            $row_array = (array)$item;
            $site_id = $item->site_id;

            $user_plants = "SELECT A.user_plant_id, A.site_id, A.plant_id FROM user_plants A RIGHT JOIN sites B ON A.site_id ='".$site_id."' 
            JOIN plants C ON A.plant_id = C.plant_id GROUP BY A.user_plant_id";
            $resultSet = $this->conn->query($user_plants);

            $user_plants = array();
            if ($resultSet-> num_rows > 0) {

                while ($item = $resultSet->fetch_object())
                    $user_plants[] = $item;

                foreach ($user_plants as $item) {
                    $row_array['user_plants'][] = (array)$item;

                    $plant_id = $item->plant_id;
                    $user_plant_id = $item->user_plant_id;


                    $plant_images = "SELECT A.plant_image_id FROM plants_images A WHERE A.plant_id ='".$plant_id."' UNION SELECT B.plant_image_id FROM user_plant_image B JOIN user_plants C ON B.user_plant_id ='".$user_plant_id."' WHERE C.user_id ='".$user_id."' GROUP BY B.plant_image_id ORDER BY plant_image_id";
                    $resultSet = $this->conn->query($plant_images);

                    $plant_images = array();
                    if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {

                        while ($item = $resultSet->fetch_object())
                            $plant_images[] = $item;


                        foreach ($plant_images as $item) {

                            $row_array['user_plants'][]['plant_images'][] = $item;
                        }

                    } else if ($resultSet->num_rows == 0) {
                        $row_array['plant_images'] = [];
                    }
                }

                $json_response[] = $row_array;
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    return $json_response;
```

The result of above code:

```
[
  {
    "site_id": "1",
    "user_plants": [
      {
        "user_plant_id": "1",
        "site_id": "1",
        "plant_id": "1"
      },
      {
      "plant_images": [
          {
            "plant_image_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "plant_image_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "plant_image_id": "3"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How should I adjust the foreach loops above to cater for this?

Comment: These nested/iterated queries are a bad idea ftom the very start.  Before fixing your result array, we need you to gather all data via one trip to the database.  Please create a minimal yet sufficient db fiddle so that we can properly help you.

Comment: A tip for nesting loops; re-using a variable name can make it confusing when trying to debug. The main issue here is that you're not referencing an index on `["user_plants"]` when add `["plant_images"]` so it's instead pushing to that array rather than adding a property.

Comment: @moh neither of the answers below are what I would call "professional". Iterated queries using the result set of a parent query is never great.  Doing it with nested foreach loops is super not great.  There are too many potential trips to the database when only one trip should be made.

Comment: Dear @mickmackusa,
Could you tell me how I make that professionally with only one trip, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: If I can find the time to do this work for you, I will first require you to provide the essential db data in a phpize.online demo link.  Once you have provided that, it should be sede imple for any descent php dev to construct the necessary sql and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of room for improvement in this code but I've ignored that and tried to keep the code matching yours in this example.

The main changes are:

- Create a temporary variable `$user_plant_array` which we store "plant_images" against
- Push that temporary variable to the `$site_array` at the end of the loop
- Rename some loop variables to making it easier to identify what you're referencing

```php
$json_response = array();
$sites = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($site = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $sites[] = $site;
    }

    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        $site_array = (array)$site;
        $site_id = $site->site_id;

        $user_plants = "SELECT A.user_plant_id, A.site_id, A.plant_id FROM user_plants A RIGHT JOIN sites B ON A.site_id ='" . $site_id . "' 
            JOIN plants C ON A.plant_id = C.plant_id GROUP BY A.user_plant_id";
        $resultSet = $this->conn->query($user_plants);

        $user_plants = array();
        if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {

            while ($user_plant = $resultSet->fetch_object())
                $user_plants[] = $user_plant;

            foreach ($user_plants as $user_plant) {
                // create a temporary variable here that we will map
                // all "plant_images" to
                $user_plant_array = (array)$user_plant;

                $plant_id = $user_plant->plant_id;
                $user_plant_id = $user_plant->user_plant_id;


                $plant_images = "SELECT A.plant_image_id FROM plants_images A WHERE A.plant_id ='" . $plant_id . "' UNION SELECT B.plant_image_id FROM user_plant_image B JOIN user_plants C ON B.user_plant_id ='" . $user_plant_id . "' WHERE C.user_id ='" . $user_id . "' GROUP BY B.plant_image_id ORDER BY plant_image_id";
                $resultSet = $this->conn->query($plant_images);

                $plant_images = array();
                if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {

                    while ($plant_image = $resultSet->fetch_object())
                        $plant_images[] = $plant_image;


                    foreach ($plant_images as $plant_image) {
                        $user_plant_array['plant_images'][] = $plant_image;
                    }
                    
                } else if ($resultSet->num_rows == 0) {
                    $user_plant_array['plant_images'] = [];
                }
                
                // the temporary variable now contains all "plant_images"
                // now we can push that to the site array
                $site_array['user_plants'][] = $user_plant_array;
            }

            $json_response[] = $site_array;
        }
    }
}

return $json_response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate answer as an alternate solution with some code improvements.

"Improvements" being more readability and/or more performant.

A few of the main changes I would suggest as "improvements" have been implemented in this example. The main ones being:

- Using prepared SQL statements (not always required but good practice to use, especially in anything accepting user input, also can make for cleaner code)
- Reducing the amount of loops (in a few places you were looping just to create an array and then looping again)
- Returning/continuing early where possible (helps to prevent unnecessary nesting)
- Removing unnecessary if statements (e.g. most of the while loops will be skipped if the results are empty - checking beforehand isn't entirely necessary)
- More readable variable names (it's common for new coders to try and abbreviate a lot of variables and often take it too far - making them readable will save you a lot of time when debugging)

The code using `mysqli` might not be the best as I generally work with `PDO`.

```php
function getSitesData() {
    // assumes that $user_id is set somewhere before this
    // assumes that $this->conn references a valid database connection

    $sql = "SELECT A.site_id FROM sites A WHERE A.user_id = ? GROUP BY A.site_id";

    $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $query->execute();

    $site_result = $query->get_result();

    $sites = [];
    while ($site = $site_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // using fetch_assoc gives us an associative array

        // initialise empty array
        $site["user_plants"] = [];

        // get user_plants
        $sql = "SELECT A.user_plant_id, A.site_id, A.plant_id FROM user_plants A RIGHT JOIN sites B ON A.site_id = ? 
            JOIN plants C ON A.plant_id = C.plant_id GROUP BY A.user_plant_id";

        $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param("i", $site["site_id"]);
        $query->execute();

        $user_plant_result = $query->get_result();
        while ($user_plant = $user_plant_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // intialise empty array
            $user_plant["plant_images"] = [];

            // get plant images
            $sql = "SELECT A.plant_image_id FROM plants_images A WHERE A.plant_id = ? UNION SELECT B.plant_image_id FROM user_plant_image B JOIN user_plants C ON B.user_plant_id = ? WHERE C.user_id = ? GROUP BY B.plant_image_id ORDER BY plant_image_id";

            $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param("iii", $user_plant["plant_id"], $user_plant["user_plant_id"], $user_id);
            $query->execute();

            $plant_image_result = $query->get_result();
            while ($plant_image = $plant_image_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $user_plant["plant_images"][] = $plant_image;
            }

            $sites["user_plants"][] = $user_plant;
        }

        $sites[] = $site;
    }

    return $sites;
}
```